# Custom Error page | Redirect type =301?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

I guess this may be a novice question ( Which I am :) ).
While redirecting user to custom error page, for e.g. 404, to tell that page wasn't found, the type of this redirect is 302.

```
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Utility/Error404.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="/Utility/Error404.aspx" />
```

Is it possible to make this redirect 301 through Web.config?

Thanks in advance to you all code maniacs.

Comment: You should be careful with a 301 as some clients will update their stored links. This might mean that a temporary glitch resulting in a 404 (perhaps during a manual publish?) would break their links permanently. From rfc2616 `The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned URIs. Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically re-link references to the Request-URI to one or more of the new references returned by the server, where possible. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this, and returning custom view with correct HttpCode :

On your web.config, remove error elements and set :

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

On your Global.asax, use this to render custom asp.net MVC View :

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
        if (ex == null)
            return;
        while (!(ex is HttpException))
            ex = ex.GetBaseException();
        var errorController = new ErrorsController();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        var httpException = (HttpException)ex;
        var httpErrorCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(errorController.GetErrorGeneratedView(httpErrorCode, new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

On your custom ErrorsController, add this to generate html view from asp.net mvc view :

```
    public string GetErrorGeneratedView(int httpErrorCode, HttpContextBase httpContextWrapper)
    {
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
        routeData.Values["action"] = "Default";
        httpContextWrapper.Response.StatusCode = httpErrorCode;
        var model = httpErrorCode;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContextWrapper, routeData, this);
            var viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "Default");
            ViewData.Model = model;
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewEngineResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewEngineResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
```